# Error: More than one file name has been given

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to change tags of my all mkv files.
I installed MKVToolNix.
My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import subprocess
import re

neredebu='/home/pi/hrc2/Film-Dizi/duzenle'

for kokdizin, altdizinler, dosyalar in os.walk(neredebu):
    for dosya in dosyalar:
        if dosya.endswith('.mkv'):

            isim=re.findall('([\w\d.]*)\.[\d]{4}\.m1080p.',dosya)[0]
            isim=isim.replace(".", " ")
            yil=re.split('[\w\d.]*\.([\d]{4})\.m1080p.',dosya)[1]
            title=isim+" - "+yil+" _ www.netmanyagi.com"

            dosyayolu=kokdizin
            dosyatam=dosyayolu+"/"+dosya

            bashCommand = "mkvpropedit "+dosyatam+" --edit info --set \"title="+title+"\""
            process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            output, error = process.communicate()
            #output = subprocess.check_output(['bash','-c', bashCommand])
            print(output)

            print("---")
```

I'm getting this output:

```
b"Error: More than one file name has been given ('/home/pi/hrc2/Film-Dizi/duzenle/The' and 'Hero').\n"
---
```

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: Give you command as a list as shown in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) and it will work.

Comment: Can you write sample code please?

Comment: The docs are full of examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that one of your `.mkv` files contains a space in its filename. Thus when you split the `bashCommand` to create a list, you inadvertently split the filename into two pieces.

The easiest thing would be to rename the file so that it doesn't contain a space. It may also be safer to build the list manually, rather than relying upon `split()`, and ensure you wrap the filename in quotes.

```
bashCommand = [
    'mkvpropedit',
    '"{}"'.format(dosyatam),
    '--edit',
    'info',
    '--set',
    '"title={}"'.format(title)
]
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I changed the codes as: bashCommand = ['mkvpropedit','{}'.format(dosyatam),'--edit','info','--set','title={}'.format(title)]
It's working.